# Question about divisibility of conductors into subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having some trouble regarding question b(ii) and b(iii). Hint appreciated.

[image]

It is not stated as such, but I believe $p$ is the conductor of $w$ into $Z[\alpha, v]$, whereas $q$ is any polynomial that conducts $v$ into $Z[\alpha, w]$. Here I am using $Z[\alpha, v]$ to denote the cyclic subspace generated by $v$. I know that if $j$ any polynomial such that $j(\alpha)v \in Z[\alpha, w]$, and $q$ is the minimal polynomial of the set $\{f(x): f(\alpha)v \in Z[\alpha, w]\}$, then $j(x) \mid q(x)$. So I only need to show the minimal polynomial of the set $\{f(x): f(\alpha)v \in Z[\alpha, w]\}$ divides $p(x)$. I know $p$ is the minimal polynomial of the set $\{f(x): f(\alpha)w \in Z[\alpha, v]\}$ as well.

But here are a few things I have trouble showing:

1) Why must the degree of $q(x)$ be $\geq$ the degree of $p(x)$?

2) How do you show b(ii) and (iii)? I could not think of any good ways to approach the problem. The obvious thing I tried is assuming (1) is true, I let $q(x)=h(x)p(x)+r(x)$ for some $h(x)$. Then do $q(\alpha)w=h(\alpha)p(\alpha)w+r(\alpha)w$ and since $p(x)w \in Z[\alpha, w] \cap Z[\alpha, v]$. I would like to show that $q(\alpha)w \in Z[\alpha, v]$ to get a contradiction with $r(\alpha)w$, but I can't think of any ways to do it. A similar problem occurs if I consider $q(\alpha)v=h(\alpha)p(\alpha)v+r(\alpha)v$. I can't find a way to show that $p(\alpha)v \in Z[\alpha, w]$ to get the desired contradiction.

Hints appreciation for b(ii) and (iii).

Comment: How do you know that the sets $\{f(x): f(\alpha)v \in Z[\alpha, w]\}$ and $\{f(x): f(\alpha)w \in Z[\alpha, v]\}$ have the same minimal polynomial?

Comment: Right, I don't know that. I'm trying to prove it. But after seeing your answer I realised it might not be completely true.

Comment: All right, that makes sense. Also, couldn't really think of a direct argument for your first question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part i:** This is a consequence of our assumption that $m(w) = 0$, which implies that $m \in \{f: f(\alpha)w \in \langle v \rangle_\alpha\}$.

**Part ii:** Let $r(x) = \frac{m(x)}{p(x)}$ (which we know is defined by part i).  We have 
$$
p(\alpha)(w) = q(\alpha)(v) \implies\\
r(\alpha)p(\alpha)(w) = r(\alpha)q(\alpha)(v) \implies\\
0 = m(\alpha ) w  = r(\alpha) q(\alpha)(v) \implies\\
m(x) \mid r(x)q(x)\implies\\
p(x) = \frac{m(x)}{r(x)} \mid \frac{r(x)q(x)}{r(x)} = q(x).
$$

**Part iii:** Take $p,q$ as in part ii, and $r = \frac qp$.  We have $q(x) = r(x) p(x)$. It follows that
$$
p(\alpha) w = q(\alpha)v = p(\alpha) r(\alpha)v.
$$
So, taking $h = p$ yields our desired conlcusion.